# Why do my equation labels print with question marks?

Tags: equations, labels

I have a problem because when I add labels to equations (Pic.1), they appear in the margins of the text (Pic.2). If I do not add a label it gets a question mark in the margin. Unfortunately the Overleaf documentation does not solve my problem.

Thanks for everything.
Draqun

Pic.1

[image]

Pic.2

[image]

main.tex

```
\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:thread}
    T_{P} = \{t_i|i=0...\alpha\}, \alpha \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

MasterDoctoralThesis.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\newcommand{\classname}{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[2017/08/27 v1.6 LaTeXTemplates.com]
\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\newbool{nolistspace}
\newbool{chapteroneline}
\newbool{listtoc}
\newbool{toctoc}
\newbool{parskip}
\newbool{hyperrefsupport}
\booltrue{hyperrefsupport}
\newbool{headsepline}
\newbool{consistentlayout}

\DeclareOption{nohyperref}{\boolfalse{hyperrefsupport}}
\DeclareOption{nolistspacing}{\booltrue{nolistspace}}
\DeclareOption{liststotoc}{\booltrue{listtoc}}
\DeclareOption{chapterinoneline}{\booltrue{chapteroneline}}
\DeclareOption{toctotoc}{\booltrue{toctoc}}
\DeclareOption{parskip}{\booltrue{parskip}}
\DeclareOption{headsepline}{\booltrue{headsepline}}
\DeclareOption{consistentlayout}{\booltrue{consistentlayout}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{\baseclass}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=nty,isbn=false,abbreviate=false,natbib=true,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Comment: Did you try running it more than once? The second run should resolve the `?` issue.  Also, instead of an image, it is always better to provide a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill overleaf compiles as many times as needed by one compilation click...

Comment: ...and you probably have a package like showlabel or showkeys loaded. Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes

Comment: Now we can only guess, what is going on in your document. Please provide code for complete small document, which we can test as it is and which reproduce your problem

Comment: `\label` does not make any printed output it is just an internal identifier for use with `\ref`  you wil have shokabel or similar debug package loaded to make the internal label visible. But please do not post code as an image it makes it hard for anyone to debug it for you,

Comment: Thanks all for quick response. I put the code which allow reproduce the problem.

Comment: Rmano's link has a link to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497.  Please read through that to see how to simplify this down to a *Minimal* Working Example.  What you've posted is far too much.

Comment: I've hope it is minimized enough :)

Comment: That was enough for an answer.  For future reference, you could also trim the class file quite a bit more.  That might have been enough for you to narrow the problem down to `refcheck`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is loading the package [`refcheck`](https://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck?lang=en).  By default, that package will print the labels in the margins.  If you don't have a reference to that label in your document, it will also include the `?` (and add a warning to the log file).  To disable both the `?` and the label printing, add the command `\norefnames` to your preamble before the `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Right. I forgot about refcheck. Thanks a lot!!! Best regards.